# Route all URL's to Home controller action C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, webapi

I want to create a URL re-director in c#, so whenever my MVC application base url is hit with parameters i want to redirect it to other url based on parameters in the url (site, folder, file, id, etc)
Eg: http://localhost:8080/site/folder/file/id or http://localhost:8080/site/folder/file or http://localhost:8080/site/folder etc.
So request url can be of any type, only base url will be fixed.

I tried to update the default route as

```cs
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Also i tried to create a custom new route as

```cs
routes.MapRoute(
    "DCTM",                                             // Route name
    "Da/{objectId}",                                    // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Redirector" }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

But both the above approaches are giving error. What can be done to achieve this?

Comment: Can you give a specific example of the incoming URL? When you say "parameters in the URL", do you mean, for example, that you want to convert something like `http://localhost:8080?site=x&folder=y&file=z&id=1` into `http://localhost:8080/x/y/z/1`?

Comment: Incoming URL : http://localhost:8080/x/y/z/1, I want to read x,y,z from the url and redirect it to some other url which have that x,y,z parameters

Comment: And what is the "some other URL"...what would that URL look like? We can't suggest a solution if you don't provide a specific example. Also bear in mind that the point of routing in MVC is to direct to a specific action method. Can you explain the purpose of transforming your URL exactly? Surely you just need to ensure that if the user types `localhost:8080/x/y/z/1` that it goes to the correct action. What's the reason for wanting to change it, what will it achieve for you?

Comment: i have clearly mentioned all stuffs in question

Comment: With respect, if you had mentioned everything, then I wouldn't be asking you to clarify it. So tell us clearly, if the user puts `localhost:8080/x/y/z/1`, what do you want to do with it, and why? You said you want to redirect it to another URL, but you haven't said what that URL should be, or how any of it relates to your controllers and actions.

Comment: i want to have a iis hosted application, which will take values from url (document id) and redirect user to a sharepoint document.
with due respect if you have got the case then only respond to this thread with solution not with other question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221635/discussion-between-mayuresh-jaiswal-and-adyson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the solution!!!
Redirect any incoming url of a web app to any other web app as below

- Update the RouteConfig.cs as

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "Dctm",
                 url: "{*nodeAliasPath}",
                 defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Redirector", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
             );
        }
```

- Now add the destination url and append the url of source to it in HomeController.cs as

```
 public ActionResult Redirector()
        {
            string destinationURL = "Destination base url" + Request.RawUrl; // combine the destination base url and source url parameters. 
            return Redirect(destinationURL);
        }
```

Output:

- Source URL: https://localhost:44306/Abc/Xyz/632-sn232-erh4
- Redirect URL: https://localhost:44396/Abc/Xyz/632-sn232-erh4

Comment: I'm glad you found something which works for you. But actually for such a simple case such as the example you've given, where you are only changing the base URL, an IIS rewrite rule could do the same job with far less overhead than an MVC application. (And those rules can handle more complex cases too).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @ADyson, but i need to go with this approach as its a small step in a hug logic so need to do this in MVC only

Comment: I'm not saying you don't need an MVC application for your other logic, but I'm saying you don't need it for this particular task.